# Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml while retrieving wsdl

Tags: java, c#

I have simple web service:

```
package tst;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class TstService {
    @WebMethod
    public int tst(String data)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args ){
        System.out.println("starting test service");
        Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:1234/TstService", new TstService());
        System.out.println("test service started");
    }
}
```

Trying to add web service reference to C# application by giving WSDL address. During this procedure Java side throws exception:

```
Sep 06, 2018 12:09:08 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit handle
SEVERE: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:299)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:341)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$500(HttpAdapter.java:90)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:689)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:82)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Sep 06, 2018 12:09:08 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit handle
SEVERE: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:299)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:341)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$500(HttpAdapter.java:90)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:689)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:82)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Classes in C# side are generated and I can call service. But why I'm getting exception and how to fix that?

Comment: Hi text/xml is the SOAP 1.1 content type and application/soap+xml is the content type for SOAP 1.2. . I think you are calling into 1.1 therefore you should change the C# side to use text/xml

Comment: Exception is thrown during `add reference` procedure in C#. Where I can change it to SOAP1.1 ?

Comment: Have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161740/soap-service-as-service-reference-in-net and the answer posted there. It appears that  basicHttpBinding is the only one that supports SOAP 1.1. Also if you refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d3ca9dba-1324-4418-ae21-5b98011b5ad1/visual-studio-2013-add-service-reference-not-working-with-sas-bi-94-webservice-soap-11?forum=wcf you will see mentioned that "web service is a SOAP 1.1 service, then which binding are you using? I will recommand you use basicHttpBinding which defaults to SOAP 1.1 service."